# Right JOIN in composite key - Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I try to find the lines where data is available only in table B but this SQL code is not working correctly, the result is the same us an inner join

```
 SELECT DISTINCT B.code_localisation, B.nom_poste, B.Batiment, B.Panneau
 FROM A RIGHT JOIN B 
 ON (A.code_localisation = B.code_localisation) AND (A.Panneau = B.Panneau)
 WHERE (A.code_localisation IS NULL AND A.Panneau IS NULL)
```

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means.

Comment: I should only have records of B that doesn't exist in A with the 2 composite keys: Panneau and code_localisation. when I did so, I found all the records of an inner join. It's like the where statement is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1
                  from a
                  where a.code_localisation = b.code_localisation and
                        a.Panneau = b.Panneau
                 );
```

This should be equivalent to your `right join`, so I'm not 100% sure it will fix your problem.

Comment: still, the same result

Comment: @H_B . . . Keys that you think are matching are not.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the where clause inside the join,

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.code_localisation, B.nom_poste, B.Batiment, B.Panneau
 FROM A RIGHT JOIN B 
 ON (A.code_localisation = B.code_localisation AND A.Panneau = B.Panneau
AND A.code_localisation IS NULL AND A.Panneau IS NULL)
```

Comment: What is this ..?

Comment: solved by adding not null to the keys of table B in the where statement

Comment: Then in your question nowhere you have mentioned the conditions to be used